# Add file to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your Info.plist WebView React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, info-plist

I'm implementing a payment platform in the app that I'm building so the payment form is shown on a `WebView` Now the form loads okay, but when I change something like I select a payment method from the drop-down web page loads to show options accordingly. But after that refresh it takes me back to  the original state as in the page was never changed and throws a warning that reads:

> Error opening URL:  [Error: Unable to open URL: file:///private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/457E6674-DA77-4676-A2CF-3F21C9572B57/mnopqmobile.app/entry.asp. Add file to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes in your Info.plist.]

While searching for this I've added this in my `info.plist` file:

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>file://</string>
  </array>
```

And here is the `WebView` component:

```
        <WebView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            useWebKit={true}
            source={{ html: paymentGatewayHTMLResponse }}
            startInLoadingState={true}
            scrollEnabled={true}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            originWhitelist={["file://"]}
        />
```

But it still throws that warning and takes me back to the original page.

Answer (score -3):

i got this warning too and i changed my code as follows and it worked.

```
<Key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</Key>
  <array>
      <string>URL</string>
  </array>
```